Open Laserkraftwerk doors with stealth?
Is there a way to open the Laserkraftwerk doors, with the laser icon on it, without putting the enemies on alert?

In previous installments, the LKW could be used in cutting mode to melt obstacles while remaining in stealth. Since that mode was removed entirely in Yound Blood, it appears that it is no longer possible to stealthily melt obstacles in the game.
